# Shoud I close every connection to Memcache after getting value?

Tags: php, performance, optimization, locking, memcached

I use Memcache on my server to store some useful query results. And I have a problem with performance of my server. I started investigating it and it's some kind of lock issue.

My first guess is that is Memcache.

I use it in this way:

```
    $memcacheRT = new Memcache;  
    if (not open) $memcacheRT->connect('localhost', 11221) or die ("Could not connect");
    get some values from memcache()
    //not closing
```

I open connection to memcache first time I need some data from there and leave it open until the end of the script in case I need more stuff and don't wan't to open it every time. It will close on the end of script on it's own right?

So is this approach correct?
Can it occur as a lock between concurrent page requests? How many connections can there be to one local port (11221)?
And if I change it to close every time after getting value does it affect performance that i open and close every time the connection?

Comment: you should be able to leave the connection open without penalty, just make sure you're not using any methods that try to queryout the meta-information on the slabs (lists,keys) as those lookups do lock Memcache for the duration of that query

Comment: How did you determine that it was a locking issue? I doubt memcache is your bottle neck unless your abusing it (1000> requests per load). You might want to install Xdebug and try to find what is taking the most time.

Comment: @tomaszs - CHECK YOUR QUERY - and if not mistaken, you LOCK the table instead of LOCK the memcache

Comment: `It will close on the end of script on it's own right?` Probably, but why depend on that? It's always good programming practice to clean up after yourself.

Comment: Yes, there's a good chance the lock/bottleneck is on the DB side. Especially if you're using something like MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Slow query long does not show anything and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You should keep connections open because opening connections is expensive(relative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use persistent memcache connections